# Can I avoid that Azure creates new resource groups for Kubernetes?

Tags: azure, kubernetes

When a new *Kubernetes service* is created in Azure a new *resource group* with a similar name to the cluster is also created. In this "resource group" all the disks etc. which are created from Kubernetes are stored.
Is there a way I can avoid that this sub-*resource group* is created and that all resources created from Kubernetes are put in the *resource group* where the cluster is located?

The background is that our Ops team would like to structure the *resource groups* and therefore the generated *resource group* structure is not preferred. Note that the information that this is not possible or at least not without a significant amount of effort would also be very useful for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/faq#can-i-provide-my-own-name-for-the-aks-node-resource-group), you can't create the cluster resources inside the resource group where the cluster is located.  The only option available is to provide a name for the second resource group at cluster creation.